# Can couscous substitute for acini di pepe?

Tags: substitutions, pasta

I couldn't find *acini di pepe* pasta in my nearby grocery store. Can I substitute Israeli couscous (bigger pearls than regular couscous) or do I need to find a store with a bigger selection? What are the differences between the two pastas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Overall, you should be fine. Those two are closely related, both pasta-like little pearls from extruded dough.

The main difference is that [Israeli couscous / Ptitim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptitim) is toasted, giving it a slightly nuttier flavour. For most use cases they should be useable interchangeably.

Comment: I agree with the main point that couscous should be fine. However, couscous and Ptitim are not the same. Ptitim are pasta proper, whereas couscous is made using a different process.

Answer (score 2):

They might use different types of wheat, but that's about it. There's no egg in either recipe, which sometimes differentiates pastas, but not here!